# `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be` using `std::max_element`

Tags: c++, stl

I was trying to get the element with largest size from a vector of elements, as succinct as possible. The original code looks like,

```cpp
std::cout << ((*std::max_element(rooms.begin(), rooms.end(),
          [](auto a, auto b){a.size() < b.size();})).size()) << std::endl;
```

which `g++` complains,

```
wall3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
wall3.cpp:150:47: error: ‘class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >*, std::vector<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> > > >’ has no member named ‘size’
  150 |     [](auto a, auto b){a.size() < b.size();}).size() << std::endl;
      |                                               ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bitset:47,
                 from wall3.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) [with _Iterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >*, std::vector<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> > > >; _Iterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >*, std::vector<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> > > >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2)>]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:5692:12:   required from ‘constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__max_element(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Compare) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >*, std::vector<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> > > >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:5743:43:   required from ‘constexpr _FIter std::max_element(_FIter, _FIter, _Compare) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >*, std::vector<std::set<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> > > >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2)>]’
wall3.cpp:150:45:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:143:18: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  143 |         { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I forgot to use `return` in the lambda expression. Adding `return` solved the problem.

Lesson: use a different compiler and turn on the strictest warning configurations to reveal the problem faster. The output from `clang++` is far more explicit,

```
wall3.cpp:150:33: warning: relational comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
                  [](auto a, auto b){a.size() < b.size();})).size()) << std::endl;
                                     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Lesson: write readable code. That one-liner does far too much.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to crank up the optimizer. In g++, optimizing makes the compiler spend a lot more time looking at and considering your code in order to produce more efficient output, and that closer look often exposes bugs like this that the compiler can report on.

Comment: To test the above assertion, I hacked out a quick example and got *warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]* reported with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. and no optimization flags. You might just have to up the warning level a notch or two.